# I need help making change in java. It doesnt give out change correctly

Tags: java

Hi I'm trying to make a method that gives you change in Hundreds, Fifties, Twenties, Tens, Fives, ones as well as quarters dimes and nickels. the user gives input and its supposed to look something like this: 6.87 1 five 1 one 3 quarters 1 dime 2 pennies

So far I have this as my code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 /**
  *
  * @author Cjespinomartine
  */
 public class Assignment04 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your amount");
        double amount = stdin.nextDouble();
        double remainder = Math.round(amount * 100);

        double hundreds = remainder / 1000;
        remainder = remainder / 1000;

        double fifties = remainder / 500;
        remainder = remainder / 500;

        double twenties = remainder / 200;
        remainder = remainder % 200;
        /*
        double fives = remainder / 5;
        remainder = remainder % 5;

        double ones = remainder / 1;
        remainder = remainder % 1;

        double quarters = remainder / .25;
        remainder = remainder % .25;

        double dimes = remainder / .10;
        remainder = remainder %10;

        double nickels = remainder / .5;
        remainder = remainder % .5;

        double pennies = remainder;
         */

        System.out.println(hundreds + "hundred/s");
        System.out.println(fifties + "fiftie/s");
        System.out.println(twenties + "twentie/s");
        /*   System.out.println(fives + "five/s");
        System.out.println(ones + "one/s");
        System.out.println(quarters + "quarter/s");
        System.out.println(dimes + "dime/s");
        System.out.println(nickels + "nickel/s");
        System.out.println(pennies + "cent/s");
         */
    }
 }
```

It doesn't give out change in order it just gives out hundreds. I commented some of the change because I'm trying to get the math right. I think the assignment required if and else if so if it does can you help me out with where I put it. any help will mean a lot i'm very stuck thank you.

Comment: Problem 1: Never use floating point types to represent money.

Comment: Might be helpful to express what you want it to do using Behavior Driven Development (BDD) syntax, see https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Comment: I would start by defining the available currency in a list, and looping that list.

Comment: If you need to print the names (eg. dime) you probably need a Map not a List.

Comment: `Math.round(double)` returns a `long` which is what you want to work with anyway: `long value = Math.round(amount)`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong.

The first issue is your initial handling of `remainder` – you're multiplying by 100, so if input is `1274.56`, you end up with `127456` (ignoring floating point problems which are valid but I'll stay focused on this first point). The output of `Math.round()` is either an `int` or `long`, but definitely not a `double` so you're adding confusion for yourself by storing it as a `double` – instead, store the result as `long`. From there, when you calculate `hundreds`, you need to divide by 10,000 not 1,000. Also, store that as an `int`, not a `double`. Here's what that would look like:

```
long remainder = Math.round(1274.56 * 100);
int hundreds = (int) remainder / 10000;
System.out.println("hundreds: " + hundreds);
```

The above prints out "12" for `hundreds`, which is what you want.

The second issue is how you're calculating `remainder`. You want everything that's "left over" from the prior calculation which you do by using `%` (modulus operator), and also use 10,000 instead of 1,000. For the `hundreds` case, it would be this:

```
remainder = remainder % 10000;
System.out.println("remainder: " + remainder);
```

The above code would print this:

```
remainder: 7456
```

This should give you enough to get the rest of your math working properly.

Comment: Thank you so much, for fifties would i use 500 or 5000 ?

Comment: If you’ve multiplied by 100, then you’re working with pennies and not dollars. How many pennies in $50?

Answer (score 0):

`remainder = remainder / 1000;` is wrong. What you want is the remainder after you've taken out all the hundreds. `remainder = remainder % 1000;` -looks like the commented out ones are correct...

Also don't use floating point types for money. Google will give you a thousand reasons why.

Comment: What is the fix to the floating type problem? Is it OK to just use long? (they already multiplied by 100, presumably to get the value in cents)

Comment: As I said. Google it. Basically it is because floating point is not exact and money has to be ;-) `long` is ok but you can probably get away with `int`.